# When remove the Class. nochange on class'length?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<% (1..3).each do %>
    <p id="input">
        <input type="text" name="somename"/>
        <a class="remove" >Remove</a>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

jQuery:

```
var $remove=$(".remove")

$remove.click(
function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
            alert($remove.length);
})
```

It always alerts `3`, why? Did I remove the class `remove` correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the element from the DOM doesn't destroy the reference held in `$remove`. Try  `alert($(".remove").length)` instead.

**Edit:** [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/jn6Wb/1)

Answer (score 3):

`$remove` is pointing to the value of `$(".remove")` when it is defined, it is by value not by reference. This means if `$(".remove"`) changes it will not be reflected in `$remove`. You need to query the element again before looking at the length.

Answer (score 1):

It's always three because you save the array into `$remove`

```
var $remove=$(".remove")

$remove.click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    alert($remove.length); // saved reference to $('.remove') <-- original call still 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

$remove collection of elements won't be updated automatically. However you can run the selector once more to get the result you want:

```
$(".remove").click(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
        alert($(".remove").length);
    }
)
```